# Using For Loop to Print Pattern in Java

Tags: java, loops

I need to print this:
[image]

I need to print this square using a for loop in java.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
 public static void main(String [] args)
   {

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
              System.out.print("O ");
        }
        System.out.println();
          for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            System.out.print("O ");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution would be to nest two loops, first print `O` then use a second loop to print `.`. You know that each line should have a decreasing number of `O` (and increasing number of `.`s). In fact, you have `5 - i` and `i` of each per line (where `i` is row number). And you can use the outer loop to determine how many of each should be drawn with those formulae. Like,

```
int size = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size - i; j++) {
        System.out.print("O ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print(". ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
O O O O O 
O O O O . 
O O O . . 
O O . . . 
O . . . .
```

Another option would be to create a `StringBuilder` to represent the initial conditions, print and then mutate the `StringBuilder`. This uses additional storage, but eliminates the need for nested loops.

```
int size = 5;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sb.append("O ");
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    System.out.println(sb);
    sb.setCharAt(sb.length() - (i * 2) - 2, '.');
}
```

And, you could also make that with an array of `boolean`(s) (e.g. a bitmask). Convert `false` to `O` and `true` to `.`, and set the last element offset by the index to `true` on each iteration. Like,

```
int size = 5;
boolean[] arr = new boolean[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        System.out.print(arr[j] ? ". " : "O ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    arr[size - i - 1] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a 'design pattern' problem.  You just need to use the logic with loops.
Here's the logic.

> In a square of n x n cells, the *i*th row contains (n-i) ovals and i
>   dots, where 0 <= i < n.

Refer to the other answer to see a working snippet.